# Get location from JSon when my location change

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I'm trying to get places that exist near to me from a json url, but I can only take these addresses after getting my location because so I can take the nearest places. 
In this way I am calling the method that obtains the latitudes and longitudes within the onLocationChanged.

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
MapView mapFrag;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;

 public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    mLastLocation = location;

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    loadJson(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}
```

The problem is at the way I am trying to take the Json array, using RequestQueue  and StringRequest, the method onResonse from the innerclass Response.Listener is never reached. 
And it is inside this method that I am adding markers to the map.

```
private void loadJson(double lat, double longit){
        lat = -22.950491;
        longit= -43.181609;

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://MyJsonURL";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            List<Places> arrayList = new ArrayList<Places>();
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length();i++){
                                if ((jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("latitude") != "") && (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("longitude") != "")){
                                    Places places = new Places();
                                    places.setLatitude(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("latitude"));
                                    places.setLongitude(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("longitude"));
                                                                        places.setNome(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nome"));
                                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(places.getLatitude(),escolasMaps.getLongitude())).title(places.getNome()));
                                }

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                String err = (error.getMessage()==null)?"SD Card failed":error.getMessage();
                Log.e("sdcard-err2:",err);
            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);
        queue.start();
    }
```

Another problem that I want take to solve is how can I put a value at the entry of the title of the marker, so when I click it I will send the value instead the entry.

Comment: I don't think `http://MyJsonURL` is going to respond to your request. Neither I understand why the logcat says it's trying to get something from the SD. If you want to get answers, stop questions on copy-pasted code

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at the queue.start();, this was getting one thread interruption. I had to remove this call and expand the size of the timeout for getting more time at the request.
This solve the problem.